# Why OnClick event correspond to a message ID of 0x2111 or 8465 in winform button's WndProc method?

Tags: winforms, button, wndproc

I read the source code of the Button.cs at the [.NET reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.windows.forms/winforms/managed/system/winforms/Button.cs,c038d2f6b223a3ca)，and I found the message ID for the OnClick event is 0x2111 or 8465. Shouldn't it be something like 0x0201 or 513, which is WM_LBUTTONDOWN message?

Comment: That's `WM_REFLECT` + `WM_COMMAND`. See [Message Reflection for Windows Controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/tn062-message-reflection-for-windows-controls?view=vs-2019)    Also:  [Button Messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/button-messages). `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` is related to Mouse input.

Comment: @Jimi I read the link you sent.Does it mean that the button click event is first sent by the button control to the parent form for processing, and then the event is reflected back by the parent form for processing by the child form?

Comment: It's the way to handle notifications in sub-classed Controls that use an ActiveX container Window. In Object derived from the `Control` class, the container class delegates message dispatching (input) to an Interface derived from [IOleInPlaceObject](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/oleidl/nn-oleidl-ioleinplaceobject). You can see this in the .Net [Control](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.windows.forms/winforms/managed/system/winforms/Control.cs,68). The control has the first-chance to operate on the reflected message. Find out what Ambience properties are.

Comment: See also the [COleControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/colecontrol-class?view=vs-2019) Class.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.you've helped me a lot.